# Как сообщить вызывающей стороне об ошибке в деструкторе

Tags: c++, исключения, деструктор

Какие существуют способы сообщить о проблеме, возникшей в деструкторе?

Понятно, что обычное исключение кидать нельзя, потому что деструктор может быть вызван в процессе обработки уже возникшего исключения. Но ведь в деструкторе могут возникнуть проблемы, о которых нужно будет как-то сообщить вызывающей стороне.

Например, не удается закрыть файл (или группу файлов), и простое игнорирование этой ситуации нарушит согласованность огромной базы данных.

Я и не представлял раньше, насколько серьезна эта проблема. Во всех без исключения книгах, с которыми я имел дело, предполагалось, что если в деструкторе и возникают какие-то проблемы, то они либо решаются там же, либо не решаются вообще.

Как решается эта проблема?

Comment: Если кидать исключение нельзя, а код возврата деструктор, как известно, не возвращает, то остается только один способ - завести глобальную структуру(класс) для подсчета количества сбоев. В ней же завести массив, в котором хранить коды сбоев.

Comment: Тогда проще в `stderr` выводить. Но ведь логирование информации - это одно, а реагирование - совсем другое.

Comment: Вам лучше подумать, каким образом вызывающая сторона сможет обработать такую ошибку. Обычно ошибки в деструкторе не поддаются обработке и можно спокойно вызвать `std::abort`. Пример с файлом можно обработать по аналогии с `std::thread` - если файл еще открыт при попадании в деструктор, то вызвать `std::terminate`

Comment: Это не очень хорошее решение. Как минимум потому, что в том же `C` в описанной ситуации у нас есть возможность что-то сделать, потому что мы можем передать информацию выше.

Comment: В С ситуация точно такая же - функции отвечающие за подчистку не должны иметь кода возврата или передавать что-то выше. А ситуации, когда подчистка невозможна, можно обработать вызовом abort. Суть в том, что потенциально неуспешные действия не надо пихать в функции подчистки.

Comment: Деструктор далеко не всегда используется, как чистильщик ресурсов.

Comment: Например, конструктор таймера взводит таймер, а деструктор - логирует.

Comment: Функции `CloseHandle()`, `closesocket()`, `fclose()` и многие-многие другие имеют код возврата, и могут отказать. Неужели нет способа уведомить, что в деструкторе что-то пошло не так?

Comment: Это все примеры действий, которые не следует совершать в деструкторе.

Comment: Я немного не понел. Если деструктор не делает того, что ожидалось, как это можно воспринять ошибкой?...

Comment: А [вселенная не является симметричной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Нарушение_CP-инвариантности) DDD. А проблема не в том, чтобы сообщить об ошибке в деструкторе, а в том, что при неудачном вызове конструктора программа может спокойно продолжиться больше не делая попыток создать этот объект; в то время как при неудачном вызове деструктора программа не может продолжить работу, пока деструктор не отработает успешно. Соответственно деструктор должен либо отрабатывать успешно, либо аварийно завершать работу программы.

Comment: @VTT а где же закрывать файл, как не в деструкторе? `std::fstream`

Comment: [Тогда проще в stderr выводить] Проще, но это не общий случай. Вывод в stderr это только информирование разработчика. Если надо выполнять какие-то действия при ошибке в деструкторе, то одного вывода в stderr мало.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, я об этом и говорю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос есть в [C++ super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#dtors-shouldnt-throw). Приведу основные выкладки оттуда и добавлю кое-что от себя.

Если в деструкторе произошла аварийная ситуация, можно делать всё что угодно (писать в лог, завершить процесс...), но ни в коем случае не выкидывать исключений наружу деструктора. В противном случае процесс всё равно будет завершён через `std::terminate`, если во время разворачивания стека из-за одного исключения будет вызвано (и не обработано) новое.

В современном C++ любой деструктор уже неявно помечается `noexcept`, а это значит, что попытка выкинуть из него исключение [приведёт к завершению процесса](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#5) через `std::terminate`, даже если вызывающий код имеет подходящий `try-catch`. Чтобы тем не менее иметь возможность выкинуть исключение из деструктора, нужно явно указать `noexcept(false)`:

```
struct S {
    ~S() noexcept(false) { throw 42; }
};
```

Если иметь возможность проверять наличие исключения (как предложил @Ant в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933157/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5/933308?noredirect=1#comment1547939_933308) это можно сделать путём сравнения значений, возвращаемых [`std::uncaught_exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) (с++17) в конструкторе и деструкторе объекта), то можно безопасно выбрасывать исключение из деструктора пока ещё нет другого активного исключения, не имеющего своего обработчика. Но в таком случае нужно всё равно как-то обработать ситуацию, если ошибка в деструкторе возникла при наличии такого исключения. Поэтому наиболее простой вариант - просто не выкидывать исключения, а сразу *делать что-то другое*.

**Нормальная практика - помещать операции, приводящие к исключениям, в отдельные функции и вызывать их отдельно от деструктора. Код в деструкторе должен быть максимально простым и не требовать сложной обработки, которая может породить исключение.**

Например, если вы работаете с объектом типа `std::fstream`, который закрывает файл в деструкторе, но при этом хотите иметь какую-то обработку проблемы закрытия файла, то вызовите [`std::fstream::close`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/close) отдельно и проверьте наличие `failbit` для выявления проблем. Обработайте это как душе угодно (с исключениями или без), а на последующий вызов деструктора `std::fstream` вам уже не нужно обращать никакого внимания. Здесь стоит заметить, что у `std::fstream` (через базовый класс `std::basic_ios`) есть возможность установить битовую маску для генерации исключений с помощью функции [`exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions). Если в этой маске будет присутствовать `failbit`, то деструктор может выкинуть исключение при ошибке закрытия файла (и это приведёт к завершению программы), но если это закрытие, т.е. `close()`, вызвать самостоятельно, то исключение вполне можно обработать стандартным способом.

Comment: "Если иметь возможность проверять наличие исключения..." - такой способ не дает осмысленного ответа на вопрос, когда исключения в деструкторе обрабатываются локально. "Вложенные" исключения в таком случае бросать можно, даже при наличии активного исключения, а этот метод говорит, что нельзя.

Comment: "Нормальная практика - помещать операции, приводящие к исключениям в отдельные функции, и вызывать их отдельно от деструктора..." - но это противоречит идее RAII, вокруг которой обычно и построены такие вопросы. То есть такое "решение" фактически не отвечает на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @AnT "а этот метод говорит, что нельзя" - какой метод говорит, что нельзя вложенные исключения кидать? Я же пишу далее "выбрасывать исключение **из** деструктора" - "из" - значит наружу (не локально).

Comment: Я говорю о любых методах, проверяющих наличие "текущего исключения". Наличие "текущего исключения" еще не означает, что исключения нельзя кидать.

Comment: @Ant "но это противоречит идее RAII" - противоречит ли RAII наличие возможности установить маску для генерации исключений в `std::fstream`? Ведь если её установить для `failbit` мы можем получить исключение в деструкторе, который вызовет `close`. Но если тот же самый `close` вызвать отдельно и обработать как следует, то можно избежать фейла в деструкторе.

Comment: @AnT "не означает, что исключения нельзя кидать" - так я и не утверждаю, что его нельзя кидать вообще, в частности локально. Я говорю про выкидывать **наружу**. Вроде бы тут всё нормально написано.

Comment: Ну так а как вы узнаете, выкидывается ли оно наружу или нет? Ваш объект может быть *локальным объектом* в каком-то охватывающем деструкторе. Охватывающий деструктор локально обрабатывает исключения (не дает им вылетать наружу). Этот охватывающий деструктор вызвался во время раскрутки стека при обработке какого-то внешнего исключения. То есть текущее исключение *есть*. Но бросать исключения из деструктора локального объекта *можно*, ибо они обработаются *локально*. Как деструктору локального объекта это понять?

Comment: @AnT приведите, пожалуйста, код, если можно, для демонстрации, описываемой Вами ситуации.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/611fe2ee98bd7639. Класс `Inner` "боится" бросать исключение, т.к. он видит, что в данный момент есть необработанное исключение. Но на самом деле исключение в данном случае бросать совершенно безопасно. Класс `Inner` не может узнать, безопасно это или нет. Фактически вот об этом https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741423/why-will-stduncaught-exception-change-to-stduncaught-exceptions. Но оказывается, `std::uncaught_exceptions` позволяет решить этот вопрос путем сравнения счетчиков в момент конструкции и деструкции.

Comment: @AnT любопытно получилось.

Comment: Добавление классу специализированной функции финализации, которая вызывается *вручную* перед вызовом деструктора, проблему совершенно не решает, потому что деструктор в исчерпывающем большинстве случаев вызывается автоматически, и у нас нет возможности вызвать наш финализатор перед этим процессом. Удаление временных объектов, уничтожение сложного составного объекта, стандартные шаблонные контейнеры - все это может вызвать деструктор миллионами различных способов, спасибо компилятору, который автоматически генерирует тучи определяемого реализацией кода.

Comment: А комитет (конкретно, группа Яндекса) еще и обсуждают ввод в новый стандарт автоматической семантики перемещения. Я вообще не представляю, как разгребать эту кашу. А мы ведь всего лишь хотели вытолкнуть информацию за границу деструктора, чтобы вызывающая сторона могла понять, все или не все прошло гладко...

Comment: @MGNeo совет по комментариям, нет смысла всё подряд отмечать как «полезное», это не добавляет репутации автору. Отмечайте «полезными» комментарии, которые действительно полезны для сообщения, к которому они относятся.

Comment: @älёxölüt, окей, я понял.

Comment: *"В современном C++ любой деструктор уже неявно помечается noexcept, а это значит, что попытка выкинуть из него исключение приведёт к завершению процесса (в общем случае, UB)"* А почему UB? Разве не просто автоматический `std::terminate`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat пофиксил.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим ошибка в деструкторе является причиной неуспешного завершения программы. И если я заранее имею сомнения по этому поводу, то могу в конструкторе изменить функциональность завершения. Например:

```
struct A {
    std::terminate_handler th;
    int i = 5;
    A() { th = std::set_terminate([](){ std::cerr << "error in class destructor"; }); }
    ~A() { if (i != 5) std::terminate();  std::set_terminate(th);}
};
```

И программа:

```
A a;
a.i = 0;
```

Выдаст сообшение перед завершением.  Вопрос не включает в себя конкретного примера, поэтому трудно угадать что вам нужно конкретно...

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Я пытаюсь понять, как передать вызывающей стороне информацию через границу деструктора.

Comment: Но только не генерацией исключения в деструкторе.  Если приведете конкретный пример, будет легче отвечать

Comment: Примеры: таймер, который в деструкторе пишет в файл; сетевая задача, которая в деструкторе подтверждает окончание соединения; логическое подключение, которое в деструкторе освобождает системные ресурсы; транзакция в базе данных, которая в деструкторе фиксирует все изменения.

Comment: Ну и пусть эта самая сетевая задача имеет виртуальный деструктор, запишите там что хотите, а таймер наследует от него.  Нет? Тогда я не знаю. Кстати, с первым комментарием я согласен.  И с этим:  "Это все примеры действий, которые не следует совершать в деструкторе. – VTT " тоже согласен.